# How to adjust for spatial autocorrelation in panel regression in R

Tags: r, econometrics, panel-data, autocorrelation, spatial

I am running a panel regression with two-way fixed effects, the outcome variable being the number of conflicts in each district each month.

My calculation of Moran's I seems to indicate that the conflicts exhibit spatial autocorrelation. How can I adjust for this in my panel regression in R?

I realise that this question has been asked before, but I have thus far been unable to find a satisfactory solution.